# Python discord-bot user-token doesn't work

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to use my discord bot with a user token, and I'm getting this error all the time (I tried different tokens but just normal bot-tokens worked) but I need to use user-token for my project.
I think its something with the library configuration but I don't know how to solve that either.
Source code where the error occurs:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot = DiscordBot()
    bot.run(os.environ.get('USER_TOKEN'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 247, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<here was my name>/PycharmProjects/pumpDaemon/DiscordBot.py", line 68, in <module>
    bot.run('<here is the token>')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 297, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

Comment: In .run pass the bot=False kwarg, also note that this is strongly against the discord ToS, you can get yourself banned.

Comment: Thanks that worked :) (Just saying, I'm not going to spam someone, I just want to read out some stuff.)

Comment: @Wandschranktafel which library is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
bot.run(os.environ.get('USER_TOKEN'), bot=False)
```

And you're ready to go!