# Improper token on replit

Tags: python, discord, bots

Hi i keep getting the error message

```
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
```

this is my code

```
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

token = os.environ['token'] 

async def on_ready():
  await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name=" dm for support  ;)"))

client.run("token")
```

this is the full error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 293, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 247, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 11, in <module>
    client.run("token") 
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 718, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 697, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 660, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 509, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 297, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.

```

and finally this is a screen shot of the token
[image of token in replit secrets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sWlZ.png)

> any help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that I think are the cause:

1. In this part of the code

```py
token = os.environ['token']
```

You are retrieving an environment variable, called `'token'`, that you should set before running your program. In case you haven't, that's easy to do:

**Windows**:

```
SET token=<value of token>
```

**Linux based OS**:

```sh
export token=<value of token>
```

In this way, you make sure this environment variable is set.

**Second problem**:

In this part of your code

```py
client.run("token")
```

You are not using this variable that you previously extracted with `token = os.environ['token']` , instead you are literally using the string `token` as your token, which I imagine is not really your token. This could be fixed, like this:

```py
client.run(token)
```

Note that in this case, I'm using the variable `token` previously declared, instead of the string `"token"`.

Also, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080117/python-discord-bot-user-token-doesnt-work) could be helpful.